# How do I install Highcharts for tinyMCE?

Tags: highcharts, tinymce

I've tried to download Highcharts using the tutorial in the bottom of [this page](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/charting-with-tinymce-and-highcharts/), but they skip a step, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in that step.

I've downloaded the files **highcharts-edit-tinyce.0.3.0.zip** and **highcharts-editor.dist.0.3.0.zip**, now where do I extract those?
Should I just leave them in my website's main directory, or in the **/tinymce/plugins/INSERT LOCATION**?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Dr. Dark, Have you seen this article: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-integrate-highcharts-editor-into-tinymce-editor/ about integrating Highcharts editor into TinyMCE editor.

Comment: Hey, yes I have but that too doesn't answer my question.
I have no idea where to put the downloaded files. All articles (I've found) skip that part.

Comment: Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-integrate-highcharts-editor-into-tinymce-editor-kgg89 I hope that will help.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That explained my issue! Thanks a lot for the help!